# inserting multiple records through objectset

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is there any way to insert multiple records without a loop if you already have a collection? Granted there is little performance benefit if you commit outside the loop.

I have a context and `ObjectSet<Type>`. I also have a collection of `Type` which I want to swap in or concatenate or intersect or what have you for what's in the table. In other words, I don't want to proceed from the below:

```
foreach (Type r in Collection)
{
    Context.ObjectSet.Add(r);
}
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Not too sure i understand your second paragraph though .. any pseudo-code to explain what you mean?

Comment: it seems like you want a bulk insert. is that the case?

Comment: I think a bulk insert is what I'm after. I did intuit that the add method does more than an add method on an enumerable. If whatever it does involves going to the database, then calling SaveChanges once per multiple adds doesn't amount to a bulk insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must always use loop. There cannot be any performance benefit in methods like `AddCollection` or `AddRange` because these methods usually works on some performance optimization where internal collection is extended for whole range and it is just copied instead of extending collection for each `Add` call. `AddObject` does much more then passing data to some internal collection so it still have to process entities one by one.

If you want to optimize performance of database inserts themselves you must move to another solution because EF doesn't have any batch or bulk data modifications. Each record is passed as single insert in separate roundtrip to the database.

Comment: Thank you. In general, the problem I'm faced with, as I start with EF, is where to house the logic that will alter many records in many tables based on contents of many others. Your answer indicates that pulling the pieces into memory may not be the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating an extension method to do the looping and adding.
see below.

```
public static class AddHelper 
{


   public void AddAll(this ObjectSet<T> objectSet,IEnumerable<T> items)
   {

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
           objectSet.AddObject(item);

        }

   }

}
```

Then you could use the code below.

```
 IEnumerable<EntityName> list = GetEntities(); //this would typically return your list
 Context.ObjectSet.AddAll(list);
```

Comment: Thank you -- that would at least hide that logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same type of solution.

I have yet to find a way to do it directly with EF, but there is a way to do it. If you create a Stored Procedure that accepts a DataTable as a parameter, you can execute the PROC with Entity Context and pass the table as a parameter.

When you're dealing with thousands or millions of records, this is a lot better than looping through each record to be passed to DB.

[Passing Table Valued Parameters to SQL Server Stored Procedures.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)